# Problem with query to update foreign key column

Tags: php, sql

I am working on a cms for properties/ads in oop php for learning purposes. I have three tables that are connected with pivot table.

```
photos (id, name, extension), 

property_photo (id, property_id, photo_id), 

properties (id, title, description, main_photo_id)
```

I have a gallery of photos for every property and I am trying to be able to insert main photo (one of existing photos in gallery) for each property through foreign key (main_photo_id) and display that photo on a different page. I am having trouble writing function (query) in model. Any help is much appreciated. Here is some of my code:

AdModel:

```
public function MainPhotoInsert($id)
{   
    $this->db->query('INSERT INTO properties (main_photo_id) VALUES (:main_photo_id) SELECT id FROM PHOTOS WHERE id = :id LIMIT 1');
    $this->db->bind(':id', $id);
    $row = $this->db->single();

    return $row;
}
```

AdsController:

```
public function galleryAction()
 {
    if (!isset($_GET['id'])) {
        $photo_id = $_SESSION['photo_id'];
    } else {
        $photo_id = $_GET['id'];
    }

     if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        $_POST = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); 

        if(isset($_POST['radio']))
        {
            $this->AdModel->MainPhotoInsert($photo_id);
            redirect('ads/index');
        }   
    }

    $data = $this->AdModel->getPhotosForProperty($photo_id);
    $data1 = $this->AdModel->MainPhotoData($photo_id);

    $this->view->render('ads/gallery', $data, $data1);
 }
```

gallery.php:

```
<form action="/ads/gallery?id=<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>" method="POST">

  <?php foreach ($data as $key => $value) : ?>

        <img src="<?php echo '/public/photos/'.$value->name.'.'.$value->extension ?>" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" width="250" height="250">
        <input type="radio" name="radio" value="<?php echo $value->photo_id; ?>" >Make main
    <br>

  <?php endforeach; ?>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-success form-control">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Where do you do the `INSERT` in `MainPhotoInsert` ? I only see a `SELECT`

Comment: @MickaëlLeger I accidentally put the wrong method. I edited the post now, but I really don't know how to correctly write insert method for this. Can you help?

Comment: `MainPhotoInsert` is inserting and selecting in the same query.  This will fail. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Your updated form is still trying to pass the ID into the get string of the form action. You probably want to remove that since everything else is getting set via post (you could use a hidden input to send it).

Comment: @Martin I am trying to  insert main photo (one of existing photos in gallery) for each property through foreign key (main_photo_id) in properties table and display that. I know query is bad I just don't know exactly how to write it to work

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have a `select` clause in your insert statement (at least not for what you are trying to do). IF you only ever need to set it once then you need to tweak the query to include the other two values (title and description) or they will always be blank. It should end up looking something like this:

```
INSERT INTO properties (main_photo_id, title, description) VALUES (:main_photo_id, : title, : description)
```

More likely, you want an *upsert* (update if a relevant row already exists, insert if one doesn't). In MySQL the syntax is [`insert ... on duplicate key update`](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-insert-if-row-does-not-exist-upsert-in-mysql/). This means you are going to need a primary key on the properties table (it's unclear if you already have one). The syntax is pretty similar to the insert above but without knowing the exact structure of the table I can't give you the exact query.

Update:
The `on duplicate key` syntax would look something like this (it depends on how you have your primary key set up on the table, e.g. if main_photo_id is the primary key then this likely won't work):

```
INSERT INTO properties 
    (id, main_photo_id, title, description) 
VALUES 
    (:id, :main_photo_id, : title, : description)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    main_photo_id = :main_photo_id, 
    title = :title, 
    description = :description
```

Side note:
gallery.php is also going to produce a separate HTML form for each image with one radio button on the form which isn't really what you want. You should move the form to wrap around the entire `foreach` loop so that you have one form. Then you should put the image ID as the value for the radio button.

Comment: I have primary key on properties table and I edited gallery.php, also I edited post. Still I'm having trouble writing insert query, I just don't know what exactly I'm supposed to do. Can you help?

Comment: The first half of the query looks good if all you are doing is an insert (never need to update), just drop everything after `select`

Comment: Read the linked article on how to use insert ... on duplicate key update (https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-insert-if-row-does-not-exist-upsert-in-mysql/)

Comment: I did everything like you said.Now I am having trouble binding values. Should I go like this  $this->db->bind(':title', $data['title']);  $this->db->bind(':main_photo_id', $id); and thne pass and then pass $data in function or something else

Comment: but I don't have anywhere now main_photo_id that is foreign key in properties table that connects to id (that is primary key) from photos table. Please

Comment: @Marko: I updated the suggested query to account for the ID in the properties table. Yes, you'll need to bind id, main_photo_id, title, and description to use the query as I have it structured. I'm assuming that you have all of those fields (although I'm not seeing them in your HTML, I assume they are in your table because you have them).

Comment: Yes i have those fields and some more, but I didn't put them here because they are irrelevant. I would of course add them in code I just need first to find correct query. And just, how is main_photo_id connected to id in photos table?